# querying multiple columns sql. Ret title column for match and return title of row for address column match

Tags: sql

I'm looking for the RIGHT way to query columns for match (got it working). But then there's this-> AND the address column for match in which I would want only the title of that row returned. This would include 'search by town' within a keyword search. Pro ideas? And thanks!

```
//works!
SELECT * FROM beaches
WHERE title LIKE '%".$input."%' 
//doesn't work at all
AND 
SELECT title FROM address WHERE LIKE '%".$input."%'
```

UPDATE:

@LittleBobbyTables
That's it!  That is how you query multiple columns with a search query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM beaches 
WHERE (title LIKE '%".$input."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$input."%')
```

As for the other helpful answer I thought JOINS where for querying over TABLES, but what do I know? I couldn't understand the single missing apostrophe. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to include only the `title` column from the `address` table, then you need to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT title 
FROM beaches
WHERE title LIKE '%".$input."%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT title 
FROM address 
WHERE title  LIKE '%".$input."%'
```

But the problem with this approach is that the columns returned by the first query needs to match the columns returned by the second query.

Comment: That's what I want, but it's giving an error. Are you sure it's "SELECT title 
FROM address 
WHERE title  LIKE '%".$input."%  ?

Comment: @user1440240, as LittleBobbyTables pointed out I forget an apostrophe at the end of the second `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yeah I can't get that to work. But the other answer (that is now gone) did return both... Just matching addresses. Oh well. I'll keep at it. Thanks